# how to do re-randomization test for trials used adaptive minimization with unequal allocation?

Tags: experiment-design, simulation, random-generation, clinical-trials, random-allocation

Re-randomization test is often chosen to validate the results from a study was randomized by adaptive minimization. In the case of of unequal allocation (like 2:1), it is more complicated because the center of re-randomization test distribution is not guaranteed to be 0.

Does anyone know some examples how to do re-randomization test in the unequal allocation cases?